# How to access PHP session values from a CGI python script on the same webserver?

Tags: php, python, cgi

So i have a CGI python script on my webserver that i use after a user submits a POST form on one of the php pages, now the problem is i need to pass a important value too and i cannot send it via form because its risky (also my entire website is PHP, i need python only for one function which i cannot implement using PHP because of lack of good libraries on that area in php)

i can store it on the php session for example $_SESSION['username'] but the problem is i dont know how can i access this php session value from that python script?

and i cant use escapeshellcmd()  because one of the inputs is a SQL query and using that will make the input corrupt since it escapes some characters, and using exec is risky too

so what should i do right now? how can i pass this Important value(username) to the python script?

it is important because the SQL query(the other input) gets parsed on that script based on the username and i cannot let them change it

also if you have a better solution please share it I'm really stuck here

Comment: Accessing the PHP session data from outside of PHP is much more complicated than moving the business logic from the Python script to PHP. Or landing the POST in PHP and shelling out to the Python script.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart so what should i do here? how can i pass a important value from php to python without this input getting escaped? i only need one python function that runs based on user input ( basically two input, one is a SQL query which i can validate there, but the username needs to be 100% correct and not changed by user)

Comment: I would pass things like username via command line or environment variables. The latter would be preferred because you can be sure the shell won't mess with them. Then pass the user data via stdin.

Comment: If you want to avoid the shell altogether, use something like [`proc_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

Comment: Store the data you need that was submitted to the PHP script in the database and pass the inserted id to Python. Then use Python to issue the database query against that id to retrieve the desired data. This will act exactly like a cookieless session storage. There should be no need to send an SQL string to Python from PHP. This way your Python script only needs to expect an integer id argument, rather than a formatted string that could be exploited, or interfacing with session data which is also hazardous.

Comment: @fyrye i can also use encryption tho right? encrypt the username with a good algorithm and then pass it, is this good?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart what do you think about using encryption to encrypt the username then pass the post form?

Comment: @RichardJones Why bother with encryption? You will need to deal with an additional encryption library and their differences. As well as passing the keyphrase for deciphering to Python. Just simplify your interface between Python and PHP to a single integer ID. Right now it sounds like you have mixed business logic occurring on PHP, that is then being sent to Python to process additional logic. Move all the logic to Python, use PHP to store the required data for the logic in the database, and retrieve the data from the database within Python to run the logic.